# How to set session timeout and session idle timeout in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, session-timeout

I have a simple question but not able to find solution to it. I have set session timeout of the application in the web.config as :

```
  <sessionState timeout="30" mode="InProc"/>
```

and its working fine but now I got the requirement that if the user is idle that is, he is not performing any action on the page for one minute his session should get expired. I tried to do it using form authentication as :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="1"  slidingExpiration ="false" defaultUrl="login.aspx"/>
    </authentication>
```

But its now working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that *being logged in/authenticated*  and *having a session* are separate things in `asp.net`. The session is not automatically cleared/emptied just because your authentication state changes. And the other way around, you session may expire even if you remain logged in.

Comment: @user1429080 can you suggest any solution to this problem. Thanks

Comment: Well what is it you want to happen? You have set the session to time out after 30 minutes, and the authentication time out as 1 minute. What exactly is it that's not working?

Comment: See my  requirement is  that if the user is idle that is, he is not performing any action on the page for one minute , he should be redirected to login page. But if he is working on the page his session should last for 30 minutes. Thanks

Comment: In simple words I want Idle session timeout and session timeout to be separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly (see comments by OP) then the problem is that OP wants both `slidingExpiration` and `absoluteExpiration` to be active, but with separate timeouts.

This would enable the system require a user to log back in after a certain time of idling, and to require a user to log back in after a *different* time even if the user was not idling.

Unfortunately this is not supported out of the box using `forms authentication`. You have to choose either sliding or absolute expiration. Or you have to build a workaround yourself.

You can use a very simple work around by:

- Setting the timeout of the `session` longer than the corresponding forms authentication timeout, and also longer than the desired absolute timeout:

  ```
  <sessionState timeout="35" mode="InProc"/>
  ```
- Set forms authentication to use `slidingExpiration = true`
- Create a *user logged in* timestamp in the session whenever a user logs in:

  ```
  Session["userLoggedInAt"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
  ```
- Add an `Application_PostAcquireRequestState` method to `Global.asax`:

  ```
  void Application_PostAcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
      if (context.Session != null && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
      {
          bool forceLogout = false;
          if (context.Session["userLoggedInAt"] == null)
              forceLogout = true;
          else if (!(context.Session["userLoggedInAt"] is DateTime))
              forceLogout = true;
          else if (DateTime.UtcNow > ((DateTime)context.Session["userLoggedInAt"]).AddMinutes(30))
              forceLogout = true;

          if (forceLogout)
          {
              FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
              FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
          }
      }
  }
  ```

**Disclaimer**: Code above was hacked together quickly, may not be fool proof...

**Notes**:

- Setting sliding expiration to timeout after 1 minute seems excessively paranoid. Even a *fast* user will not be able to finish any significant work in the application during that time. Even my web bank has a longer idle timeout that that. I would recommend a minimum of 5-10 minutes.
- Sliding expiration in forms authentication has an *interesting* feature: The sliding happens by updating the authentication cookie, moving the expiration date forward when the user is active. But this only happens when at least **half** the expiration time has passed. If you want to guarantee that a user can be idle for 10 minutes without getting logged out, you must therefore set the timeout to be 20 minutes.